# Evenly space elements in StackPanel

Tags: wpf

See this container where I have two elements. I want them to be evenly spaced, **as if I were using `justify-content: space-between` (or `space-around`) in an HTML flexbox**.

```xml
            <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" SelectedIndex="0" Padding="6">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Info"/>
                </ComboBox>
                <Ellipse DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

For this particular case, where I want them at either edge of the container, I've managed a workaround using a `DockPanel`.

```xml
            <DockPanel Margin="10" LastChildFill="False">
                <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" SelectedIndex="0" Padding="6">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Info"/>
                </ComboBox>
                <Ellipse DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red"/>
            </DockPanel>
```

However, this is definitely a workaround; if I had some dynamic number of elements that I wanted evenly spaced, it wouldn't work.

Off the top of my head I imagine I could wrap each element in a `StackPanel` or other container that could stretch to share the width of its container. But is there a simpler way to set equal spacing?

Using `Margin` or `Padding` on the individual elements is unacceptable. Unacceptable!!!!!

Comment: maybe `<UniformGrid Rows="1"/>` instead of StackPanel?

Comment: The only true way to get what you want is to create your own custom panel.

Comment: @Keithernet and what would be the makeup of that panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do the following:**

- use an `ItemsControl`
- with a custom `ItemsPanel` that'll be `UniformGrid`
- along a custom `IValueConverter`:

[image]

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ConsoleApp1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConsoleApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:ItemsControlToRowsConverter x:Key="ItemsControlToRowsConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding ElementName=ItemsControl, Converter={StaticResource ItemsControlToRowsConverter}}" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <Border Width="50" Height="50" Background="Red" Margin="2"/>
                <Border Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green" Margin="2"/>
                <Border Width="50" Height="50" Background="Blue" Margin="2"/>
                <Border Width="50" Height="50" Background="Yellow" Margin="2"/>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Converter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class ItemsControlToRowsConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value is ItemsControl itemsControl))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            return itemsControl.Items.Count;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Pile things up and adjust the converter to your tastes.

Comment: Seems like a great, if verbose and complex solution (I’m new to WPF and after working mostly with JS frameworks I..kind of hate it). I assume “pile things up” means “add children to the items control”, but how/why would I adjust the converter? (Also, is there really no way to bind straight to the `ItemsControl.Items.Count` directly in the XAML??

Comment: Also, from the docs: > “If no value for Rows and Columns are provided, the UniformGrid will create a square layout based on the total number of visible items.“

Comment: Absolutely, a fresh mind brings fresh insight lol, you certainly can directly bind to the property BUT (lol) the converter will not fail if that property is null (not checked, probably not but see what UnsetValue is all about). You have the base idea, now improve it !

Comment: This can be simplfied to a single UniformGrid with Columns="1". No need for an itemscontrol or value converter or binding: `<UniformGrid Columns="1"><Border...><Border...></UniformGrid>` (To get horizontal layout, set `Rows="1"` instead)